# Plugin for outlining tex files VOom does not work

Tags: sectioning, vim

I installed VIM plugin called VOom which has latex support for outlining sections and subsections and other commands. You can have a look here:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2657

After installation, I tested tex files. :Voom command creates the two-pane window but there is no section or subsections outlined in the right window. I don't know what is going wrong. Is there any known conflict of this plugin with latex-suite itself?

The author provides a screen shot of how it works:
http://vim-voom.github.io/pics/voom_latex.png

In the screenshot I see no latex-suite menus. That creates the suspicion that latex-suite might be interfering with this. Other type of files like *.vim file is working just fine.

It would have been great to have this feature working with vim-latex-suite. In case VOom does not work with latex-suite, anybody can suggest some other outlining alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

The correct command is `:Voom latex`